# Recoger datos de input type date con php

Tags: php, html

Hola me gustaria saber si estoy haciendo algo mal o si se hace de otra manera, quiero recoger el valor de un input type date con php, para luego hacer una consulta, y ordenar los registros por fecha.

un saludo

```html
<div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Fecha:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha" id="fecha" style="width: 125% !important;"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`$fecha = $_POST["fecha"];`

Comment: Si ese es todo el código que usas para "enviar" el dato a PHP, entonces te falta encerrar eso en las etiquetas de formulario HTML `<form></form>`. Aprende sobre cómo funcionan los formularios en [Mi primer formulario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form) y [HTML Forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Comment: @quinqui haría falta indicar en el form que el método es POST, porque GET es el valor por defecto y haría que su código fuese incorrecto y fallara.

Comment: El código también sería incorrecto y fallaría si el formulario, aún teniendo el método POST, se enviara mediante JavaScript cambiando el método o los nombres de los parámetros; o si el método se especificara en el `formmethod` del submit; o si... por eso digo que hace falta más código para saber qué es lo que está fallando (si es que algo está fallando, porque eso no queda claro en la pregunta). Seguramente la solución es trivial, pero no se puede saber sólo con la información proporcionada en la pregunta.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro En verdad, estamos suponiendo todo, realmente falta, como dices, que Sr. J indique más detalles :/ De todos modos, en base a lo preguntado, ya hay una respuesta, que ha asumido lo que nosotros. A ver qué dice Sr. J.